# How to use re to extract file name from full path in python?

Tags: python, python-re

I'm trying to get just the file name from an arbitrary full path using regular expressions in python. Right now I have `r"/.*?$"`, but that's currently matching everything after the first `/`.
I want to make it match everything after the last `/` instead, and thought that the `?` would do that by making match as little as possible. Does the `?` actually just make it close a re match as soon as it can rather than looking for the smallest possible match? The language in the documentation makes it seem like the latter, but the behavior suggests the former.
How do I make a regular expression that will match the file name, and/or is there another way to do this?

Comment: why not just use ```os.path.split()```?

Comment: or perhaps even better `os.path.basename()`

Comment: or use pathlib :)  https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html?highlight=pathlib#pathlib.PurePath.name

Comment: Thanks all, wound up using `os.path.basename`.